# Which article in front of O(.), Ω(.), ...?

Tags: terminology, asymptotics, landau-notation

Writing a survey, I am confronted to a very difficult and -- I dare say -- deep issue: I have many sentences mentioning or stating results of the form *"a $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ lower bound"*, or *"a $O(\sqrt{n}/\varepsilon^2)$ algorithm"*. And I am struggling to decide whether I should use "a" or "an" in front of these: is there a consensus/precedent?

(in hindsight, this may not be the best place to raise such profound questions; I was just unable to find any better one)

Comment: Use "an".  https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/

Comment: Well, I hear both "an oh(n)"-algorithm and "a big-oh(n)"-algorithm when talking with people; and the following sound is then either a vowel or a consonant.

Comment: Great question, maybe not a great CS question... I'd probably say "a lower bound of ..." instead, possibly because I'm subconsciously avoiding this rather than trying to actually figure it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it as you pronounce it: "an omega". Or, especially when it can be pronounced with a vowel or consonant, rephrase to avoid the issue: "a bound of..."